# Shapes drawn at obscure positions

Tags: java, graphics, shapes

this is a really weird bug and I can't seem to figure it out. To simplify this, I have three classes: A Canvas class (which draws the object with `Graphics2D.draw()`) then lots ob furniture classes, which can be viewed as one because all they do is return different shapes. Last I have a CustomShape class, which lets me create a new Shape based on my existing other shapes. But the shapes  are being drawn at weird places. The x any y coordinates do not match where the shape is being drawn.

Closet.java:

```
public class Closet {
    double x, y, width, height, rotation;
    Color color;
Closet() {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.width = 40;
    this.height = 40;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.color = Color.blue;
}

public Shape getShape() {
    GeneralPath closetShape = new GeneralPath();
    closetShape.append(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height), false);
    closetShape.moveTo(0 , 0);
    closetShape.lineTo(width, height);
    closetShape.moveTo(0, height);
    closetShape.lineTo(width, 0);
    // transform:

    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
    t.translate(x, y);
    Rectangle2D umriss = closetShape.getBounds2D();
    t.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation),umriss.getX()+umriss.getWidth()/2,umriss.getY()+umriss.getHeight()/2);
      return  t.createTransformedShape(closetShape);
}
}
```

CustomShape.java

```
public class CustomShape  {
double x, y, width, height, rotation;
Color color;
private Closet[] c;
CustomShape(Closet... elements) {
    this.m = elements;
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    Closet[] newC = elements.clone();
    Arrays.stream(newC).forEach(e -> path.append(e.getShape(), false));
    this.x = path.getBounds2D().getX();
    this.y = path.getBounds2D().getY();
    this.width = path.getBounds2D().getWidth();
    this.height = path.getBounds2D().getHeight();
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.color = Color.blue;
}

public Shape getShape() {
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    Arrays.stream(c).forEach(e -> path.append(e.getShape(), false));
    AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
    t.translate(x, y);
    Rectangle2D umriss = path.getBounds2D();
    t.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation),umriss.getX()+umriss.getWidth()/2,umriss.getY()+umriss.getHeight()/2);
    return t.createTransformedShape(path);
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change your Graphics2D translate/rotation instead of doing the translation and rotation inside your shapes?  That way the shapes can remain constant and you don't need to create a new Shape every time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I had transformed these Shapes before adding them to the CustomShape. That is why the x and y coordinates were wrong.